# Invoke PHP external class method from inside a PHAR

Tags: php, symfony, external, phar

I consider doing a command-line tool to make simple automated tests on website, [using BrowserKit component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/browser_kit.html).

My goal would be to package app skeleton in PHAR file, and use a YML configuration file to pass PHP file path which would contains testing intelligence per website:

*config.yml*

```
website1
  - "/home/myUser/tests/website1.php"
website2
  - "/home/myUser/tests/website2.php"
...
```

and run it this way : `testApp --tests=config.yml`

Each external php file would be a class on given model.

How can I invoke a known method of those given class, from inside the PHAR, given the PHP script path (obtained from config parsing)?

Comment: What did you try? Where did that fail?